# Installing pg gem for deploying rails app via heroku (windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Running 'heroku run rails console' I get the following error:

```
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.7453
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in
 `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is
 not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the
 minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

This is in my Gemfile :

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.1'
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after adding that line to your Gemfile?

Comment: Have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes I have ran bundle install since add the gem

Comment: in config/database.yml does it specify to use postgres?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in the config file using pg gem as well as running bundle install